# Reactive Redis subscriber not working using Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, reactive, spring-data-redis

In my controller, I have to return the result of a long-running process. So, I am leveraging Redis Pub/Sub to distribute work. However, my subscriber does not seem to be working and is not returning anything that just hangs.

This is what I am trying. I have removed some code to show the problem.

Here is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/messages")
class TestController(private val redisOperations: ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Result>) {

    @PostMapping
    suspend fun receiveRequest(@RequestBody request: Request): Result = coroutineScope {

        val subscriptionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val asyncSubscriber = async {

            redisOperations.listenToChannel(subscriptionId).awaitFirst()
        }

        redisOperations.convertAndSend(subscriptionId, Result(true, TextNode("test"))).awaitFirst()

        asyncSubscriber.await().message // This is not being resolved.
    }
}
```

Do, I need to configure anything else to make this work.

Comment: If `awaitFirst` is a suspendable function then you don't need the `async` block at all.

Comment: I know but since that did not work either so I tried this.

Comment: You have to identify what exactly "didn't work".

Comment: Basically `redisOperations.listenToChannel(subscriptionId).awaitFirst()` is just hanging and not returning anything.

Comment: Instead of adding `async` you should have removed `awaitFirst()` from the `listenToChannel()` call. Then, after sending the message, call `awaitFirst()` on the listener. But it probably won't fix the reason why your message is not arriving, and that may be an issue with something totally different.

Comment: I tried that basically `val asyncSubscriber = redisOperations.listenToChannel(subscriptionId)` and then later `return asyncSubscriber.awaitFirst().message` but it is not returning anything.

Comment: Yes, as said, this indicates the problem is not on the level of coroutines. Did you write a non-coroutine equivalent that works?

Comment: I do not think it is coroutine issue either. I have not tried this without coroutines. Not sure how to approach it without using it.

Comment: Maybe you can focus directly on the underlying problem, why is the message not being delivered. You could write some standalone code that just deals with Redis and not with REST controllers.

Comment: Ok I finally found the issue. Problem was that subscriber needs to be listening for publish event when publish event happens. Publish event happened before subscribe as a result it did not work. Is there anyway way to keep subscribers running in background when publish event happens.